# How are interfaith marriages treated in hindu scriptures?

Tags: marriage, other-religions, smriti, manu-smriti

What do smritis say about marrying someone from other faiths?

Comment: Just a thought: As when the ancient veds were written, there were no "other faiths", this religion was the only one. If you count descriptions like melechas as a separate faith or no faith, then this question may be OK, otherwise this question may stand incorrect. However, I am not sure about the scripts that were written after the invasions started.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal hinduism calls man and women dharm pati and patni! According to which a man and women can only be married if they acknowledge and follow the same religion of vedas and do hindu samskaras like namkarana and pind daan. Acc that logic all interfaith marriages should be banned unless the foreign religion person converts to sanatan dharma. Kanya daan to can only happen to person of same faith, doing a kanya daan to malecchas is sin.

Comment: the word "dharm" in "dharm pati or dharm patni" does not mean religion/faith, as a matter of fact dharm never meant religion, it means rules, law and morality, so the word "dharm pati-patni" means those who are made husband-wife lawfully, and they have legal right to be together. Apart from that, as I have never read any mention of "other faith", I never read about the rules of marriage, but my knowledge is limited, so It was only a minor thought.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal nope the mimansa shastra which deals with scriptures starts with "athatho dharma jijnasa" which means dharma is something which is inherently tied to one's religion and astika scriptures.

Comment: @Anisha - athatho dharma jijnasa does not mean dharma is inherently tied to one's religion. It means it is natural for one should develop desire to know dharma

Comment: @Carmensandiego mimansa is realted to theology or study of scriptures, since the writer of mimansa startes the scripture with dharma jijnasa it means that theology or study of scriptures in related to religion and one's dharma.